# Why an error is created when creating the token

Tags: c#, asp.net, access-token, dotnet-httpclient

```
 public static void CreateToken()
    {

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        var UserPassJson = "{\"username\": \"mucode\",\"password\": \"mypassword\"}";

        HttpContent content = new StringContent(UserPassJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response = client.PostAsync(new Uri("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"), content).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseContent = response.Content;
            string responseString = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            Console.WriteLine(responseString);
        }
    }
```

Why `response.IsSuccessStatusCode` Showing status code 401? What causes the malfunction?
What action does cause success?

Comment: [That doesn't seem to match the documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/get-an-access-token-postman/)

Comment: what is missing?

Comment: Well, in the documentation [basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) is used to pass the username and password, and the body is form-encoded data specifying `grant_type=client_credentials`. In comparison, you're adding a header `grant_type`, and passing the username and password as a JSON object.

Comment: Using async code in a non-await method is not recommended.  Your code will lock up in many real-world use cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/get-an-access-token-postman/) specifies that you should pass the username and password using [basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) and that you should pass a form-encoded body containing `grant_type=client_credentials`.

At the moment your code adds `grant_type` as a header, and posts the username and password as a JSON object in the body.

Correcting your code to do it the way the documentation says, we get:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
byte[] authBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("mucode:mypassword");
string base64Auth = Convert.ToBase64String(authBytes);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64Auth);

HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials") });

var response = client.PostAsync(new Uri("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"), content).Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var responseContent = response.Content;
    string responseString = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    Console.WriteLine(responseString);
}
```

P.S. I recommend reading [You're using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) and the follow-up [You're (probably still) using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://josefottosson.se/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/). I also recommend making this method `async` and making the chain all the way up `async` too.

Comment: Thanks so much it works!                                                                                                                Question: Does the access_token not change as long as it is not used?

Comment: I'm not sure how long it's good for with PayPal (I've not used their API). You should check `expires_in` in the response to see when it expires. Typically a lot of OAuth APIs allow you to request an "offline_access" scope, which will also provide a refresh token for when your access token expires (you use a refresh token to request a new access token), although I'm not sure if it works like this with PayPal. A search on the documentation page for "refresh" doesn't seem to reveal anything, so perhaps it's not possible on PayPal and you just need to reauthenticate if you get a 401?